# Genetic algorithm to fill timetable for school

Tags: java, beginner, genetic-algorithm

I wrote a program to fill a timetable for a school. There are some simple rules:

- Each subject has a preset number of blocks (blocks are 2 hour periods).
- Professor provide a valid hours they have to teach.
- There cannot be a subject at block and day x if there isn't any professor of that subject that can teach it at that time.

The program takes input from 2 txt files. The valid time is 5 days and 7 blocks. The amount of blocks used for teaching the subjects is less than the valide time. Every block has a code that starts with the 2 initial letters of the day (in Spanish) and the block starting from a to g (1 to 7). martes second period would be MAB (MA stands for martes and b stands for second period).

**`Main` class:**

```
package timetable;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import com.jaysi.timetable.Profesor;
import com.jaysi.timetable.Subject;

public class Main {
    public static final int popSize = 50;

    public static final int attemptLimit = 500;
    public static final int days = 5;
    public static final int blocks = 7;
    public static final int mutationChance =5;// 5/100
    public static List<Class>classes = new ArrayList <Class>();
    public static List<Candidate> population = new ArrayList <Candidate>();
    public static boolean notFound = true;
    public static int perfectFittnes = 1000;
    public static Candidate timetable = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        readFiles("profesors.txt", "subjects");
        population = generatePopulation(popSize);
        int attempt = 0;
        do{
            for (int i = 0; i<population.size();i++){
                if(population.get(i).getFitnnes()==perfectFittnes){
                    notFound = false;
                    timetable = population.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(population, new fitnnesComparator());
            evolvePop(population);
            Collections.sort(population, new fitnnesComparator());
            System.out.println("evolving pop!");
            for (int i = 0; i<population.size();i++){
                if(population.get(i).getFitnnes() == perfectFittnes){
                    notFound = false;
                    timetable = population.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("This its the general attempt number : " + attempt);
            attempt++;
            System.out.println("THIS ITS THE CURRENT POP FITTNES LEVEL:");

            for(int h = 0; h<population.size();h++){ 
                System.out.println("Candidate "+ h + ": "+ (population.get(h).getFitnnes()));
            }
        }while(notFound && attempt < attemptLimit);




    }
    private static void evolvePop(List<Candidate> population) {
        Candidate parent1 = null;
        Candidate parent2 = null;
        Candidate child1 = null;
        Candidate child2 = null;
        for(int i = (popSize/2)-1; i< population.size(); i++){
            population.remove(i);
        }
        for(int o = 0; o < ((popSize/2)/2); o++){
            int i = ((popSize/2) -1);
            parent1 = population.get(0);
            parent2 = population.get(o+1);
            child1 = crossOver(parent1, parent2);
            child2 = crossOver(parent2, parent1);
            mutate(child1);
            mutate(child2);
            mutate(parent1);
            mutate(parent2);
            population.add((i), child1);
            population.add((i)+1, child2);
            o++;

        }



    }
    private static void mutate(Candidate cand) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = rand.nextInt(days);
        int y = rand.nextInt(blocks);
        int p = rand.nextInt(classes.size());
        int chance = rand.nextInt(99);
        if(chance<(mutationChance+3)){
            cand.set(x, y, classes.get(p));
        }


    }

    private static Candidate crossOver(Candidate parent1, Candidate parent2) {
        Class[][] Timetable = new Class[days][blocks];
        Class[][] p1Timetable = parent1.getTimetable();
        Class[][] p2Timetable = parent2.getTimetable();
        Timetable[0] = p1Timetable[0];
        Timetable[1] = p1Timetable[1];
        Timetable[2] = p2Timetable[2];
        Timetable[3] = p2Timetable[3];
        Timetable[4] = p2Timetable[4];
        Candidate child = new Candidate(Timetable);
        return child;

    }

    private static ArrayList<Candidate> generatePopulation(int size) {
        ArrayList<Candidate> population = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        int attempt = 0;
        while(attempt<size){
            System.out.println("Generating candidate : " + attempt);
            population.add(generateCandidate());
            attempt++;
            }
        return population;


    }
    private static Candidate generateCandidate() {
        Candidate candidate = null;
        Class[][] candidateTimetable = new Class[days][blocks];
        boolean[]filled = new boolean[classes.size()]; 
        for (int t = 0; t<classes.size(); t++){
            filled [t] = false;
        }
        boolean notFilled = true;
        boolean allFilled = true;
        Integer [] space = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
                            21,22,23,24,25,26,27,
                            31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
                            41,42,43,44,45,46,47,
                            51,52,53,54,55,56,57};
        int[] counter = new int [classes.size()];
        for (int s = 0; s<classes.size(); s++){
            counter [s] = 0;
        }

        List<Integer> spaces = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(space));
        int xy = 0;
        while(notFilled){

            int x, y , u = spaces.size();
            if(u <= 0){
                notFilled = false;
                break;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i< filled.length; i++){              
                if(counter[i]== classes.get(i).getBlocks()){
                    filled[i] = true;
                }
            }
            for(boolean f : filled){
                if(f == false){
                    allFilled = false;

                }
            }
            if(allFilled){
                notFilled = false;
                break;
            }
            Random random = new Random();
            int size1 = spaces.size();
            int select1 = random.nextInt(size1);
            xy = spaces.get(select1);
            spaces.remove(select1);
            x = xy/10;
            y= xy%10;
            int select2 = random.nextInt(classes.size());
            if(filled[select2] != true){
            candidateTimetable[x - 1][y - 1] = classes.get(select2);
            counter[select2] ++;
            }
        }




        candidate = new Candidate(candidateTimetable);
        return candidate;
    }
    private static void readFiles(String pathProfesors, String pathSubjects) throws Exception{
        ArrayList <Profesor>profesors = new ArrayList<Profesor>();
        ArrayList <Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        FileReader profesorsTxt = new FileReader(pathProfesors);
        FileReader subjectsTxt = new FileReader(pathSubjects);
        BufferedReader readerProfesors = new BufferedReader(profesorsTxt);
        BufferedReader readerSubjects = new BufferedReader(subjectsTxt);

        //Fills Professors

        String lineP;
        String[] lineSplitP;
        ArrayList<String> avalideHoursP = new ArrayList<String>();
        lineP = readerProfesors.readLine();
        while(lineP !=null){
            lineSplitP = lineP.split("\\s+");
            //fills avalide hours
            //starts at 1 because 0 its name
            for(int i = 1; i<lineSplitP.length; i++){
                avalideHoursP.add(lineSplitP[i]);
            }
            profesors.add(new Profesor(lineSplitP[1], avalideHoursP));
            lineP = readerProfesors.readLine();
        }

        //Fills Subjects

        String lineS;
        String[] lineSplitS;
        ArrayList<String> profesorsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Profesor> profesorsThatCanTeachThis = new ArrayList<Profesor>();
        lineS = readerSubjects.readLine();
        while(lineS != null){
            lineSplitS = lineS.split("\\s+");
            //fills profesorsName
            //Starts at 2 because 0 its name 1 its blocks 
            for(int i = 2; i<lineSplitS.length; i++){
                profesorsName.add(lineSplitS[i]);
            }
            //fills profesorsThatCanTeachThis
            for(int i = 0; i<profesorsName.size(); i++){
                for(int x = 0; x< profesors.size(); x++){
                    if(profesors.get(0).getName().equals(profesorsName.get(i))){
                        profesorsThatCanTeachThis.add(profesors.get(x));
                    }
                }
            }
            subjects.add(new Subject(lineSplitS[0], Integer.parseInt(lineSplitS[1]), profesorsThatCanTeachThis));
            lineS = readerSubjects.readLine();
        }

        //Fills classes
        for(int i = 0; i<subjects.size(); i++){
            classes.add(new Class(subjects.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

**`Professor` class:**

```
package timetable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Profesor {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String>avalideHours = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Profesor(String name, ArrayList<String>avalideHours){
        this.name = name;
        this.avalideHours = avalideHours;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String[] getHours() {
        String profposhours[]=new String[avalideHours.size()];
        avalideHours.toArray(profposhours);
        return profposhours;    
    }

}
```

**`Subject` class:**

```
package com.timetable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import timetable.Profesor;

public class Subject {
    private String name;
    private int blocks;
    private ArrayList<Profesor>profesorsThatCanTeachThis = new ArrayList<Profesor>();
    public Subject(String name, int blocks, ArrayList<Profesor>profesorsThatCanTeachThis){
        this.name = name;
        this.blocks = blocks;
        this.profesorsThatCanTeachThis = profesorsThatCanTeachThis;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getBlocks() {
        return blocks;
    }
    public ArrayList<Profesor> getProfessors() {
        return profesorsThatCanTeachThis;
    }

}
```

**`Class` class:**

```
package timetable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import timetable.Profesor;
import timetable.Subject;

public class Class {
    private String name;
    private Subject subject;
    private int blocks;
    private ArrayList<Profesor> profesorsThatCanTeachThis = new ArrayList<Profesor>();
    public Class( Subject subject){
        this.name = subject.getName();
        this.subject = subject;
        this.blocks = subject.getBlocks();
        this.profesorsThatCanTeachThis = subject.getProfessors();
    }
    public int getBlocks(){
        return blocks;
    }
    public String[] getPosHours() {
        ArrayList<String[]>posHours = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<String>poshours = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i<profesorsThatCanTeachThis.size(); i++){
            posHours.add(profesorsThatCanTeachThis.get(i).getHours());
        }
        for(int x = 0; x<posHours.size();x++){
            for(int p = 0; p< posHours.get(x).length;p++){
                poshours.add(posHours.get(x)[p]);
            }
        }
        String[]PosHours = new String[poshours.size()];
        poshours.toArray(PosHours);
        return PosHours;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

**`Candidate` class:**

```
package timetable;




public class Candidate {
    static String template [][] = new String[Main.days][Main.blocks];


    private Class[][] timetable = new Class[Main.days][Main.blocks];
    private int fitnnes;
    public Candidate(Class[][] timetable){
        this.timetable = timetable;
        this.fitnnes = getFitnes();
    }
    public Class[][]getTimetable(){
        return this.timetable;
    }
    public int getFitnnes(){
        return fitnnes;
    }
    private int getFitnes(){
        template[0][0]= "lua"; 
        template[0][1]= "lub";
        template[0][2]= "luc";
        template[0][3]= "lud";
        template[0][4]= "lue";
        template[0][5]= "luf";
        template[0][6]= "lug";

        template[1][0]= "maa";
        template[1][1]= "mab";
        template[1][2]= "mac";
        template[1][3]= "mad";
        template[1][4]= "mae";
        template[1][5]= "maf";
        template[1][6]= "mag";

        template[2][0]= "mia";
        template[2][1]= "mib";
        template[2][2]= "mic";
        template[2][3]= "mid";
        template[2][4]= "mie";
        template[2][5]= "mif";
        template[2][6]= "mig";

        template[3][0]= "jua";
        template[3][1]= "jub";
        template[3][2]= "juc";
        template[3][3]= "jud";
        template[3][4]= "jue";
        template[3][5]= "juf";
        template[3][6]= "jug";

        template[0][0]= "via";
        template[0][1]= "vib";
        template[0][2]= "vic";
        template[0][3]= "vid";
        template[0][4]= "vie";
        template[0][5]= "vif";
        template[0][6]= "vig";

        int fitnnes = 1000;
        boolean allFilled = true;
        boolean[]filled = new boolean[Main.classes.size()]; 
        for (int t = 0; t<Main.classes.size(); t++){
            filled [t] = false;
        }
        int[] counter = new int [Main.classes.size()];
        for (int s = 0; s<Main.classes.size(); s++){
            counter [s] = 0;
        }
        for(int p = 0; p<Main.classes.size();p++){
            for(int i = 0; i<Main.days; i++){
                for(int x=0; x<Main.blocks;x++){
                    if(timetable[i][x] == null){continue;}
                    if(timetable[i][x].getName().equals(Main.classes.get(p).getName())){
                        counter[p]++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        for(int p=0;p<Main.classes.size();p++){     
            if(counter[p]== Main.classes.get(p).getBlocks()){
                    filled[p] = true;
            }
        }

        for(boolean f : filled){
            if(f == false){
                allFilled = false;

            }
        }
        if(allFilled == false){
            fitnnes -= 100;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< Main.days; i++){
            for(int x = 0; x< Main.blocks; x++){
                if(timetable[i][x] == null){
                    continue;
                }
                String posHours [] = timetable[i][x].getPosHours();
                boolean avalide = false;
                for(int y = 0; y<posHours.length;y++){
                    if(template[i][x] == posHours[y]){
                        avalide = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!avalide){
                    fitnnes -= 50;
                }


        }   

      }
        for(int q = 0; q<Main.days;q++){
            for(int a = 0; a<Main.blocks; a++){
                for(int aa = a+1;aa<Main.blocks; aa++){

                }
            }
        }
        return fitnnes;
   }
    public void set(int x, int y, Class xy) {
        this.timetable[x][y] = xy;

    }

}
```

**profesors.txt:**

The first word is the name and rest are the valid blocks they have to teach.

> ```
> Petidfgtti    mif mig vif vig
> Chdanales luc lud mac mad mic mid juc jud
> Lucdero   lub luc lud lue mab mac mad mae mib mic mid mie jub juc jud jue vib vic vid vie
> Ergamdsahi    lua luf maa maf mia mif jua juf via vif
> Mazza mab mac jub juc
> Puedfgbla lua lub luc lud maa mab mac mad mia mib mic mid jua jub juc jud via vib bic bid
> Chisdgatti    mib mic mid mie jub juc jud jue
> Jimensdfgdz   maa mab jua jub
> Rfdsgubino    mab mac mad mae maf mib mic mid mie mif
> Velafghsfghsco    vib vic vid vie vif
> Lucsgdro lub luc lud lue mab mac mad mae mib mic mid mie jub juc jud jue vib vic vid vie
> Atefghnas vib vic vid vie
> Fustghr lue luf lug mae maf mag mie mif mig jue juf jug vie vif vig
> ```

**Subjects.txt:**

The first word is the name of the subject, the number is the number of blocks that that subject has, and the other is the professors that can teach it.

> ```
> Matematica 2 Pettiti
> Apesca 3 Canales
> NavegacionI 4 Lucero
> TecfsPessc 2 Bergamaschi
> MeteofrodlogiaI 1 Mazza
> ComsdfunicacdfionesI 1 Puebla
> IndTecI 2 Chiatti
> Ssdpervisdfvencia 1 Jimenez
> ManiobraI 3 Rubino
> MaqufdsdasI 1 Velasco
> Equidfsfronicos 1 Lucero
> PrimerosAux 1 Atenas
> CargaEstiva 1 Fuster
> ```

The program works to a certain amount. The best fitness from the first generation is the best fitness in all the generations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not completely working. `fitnnesComparator` is missing. But still there is a lot of effort. In case you are not aware Code review is only for code that works.

You didn't add what you were expecting so I guess you were expecting a fix. Sorry.

I won't solve the problem but I will add some general things that can be improved in the code.

**Use for-each loop if you don't need the index**

Instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i<subjects.size(); i++){
        classes.add(new Class(subjects.get(i)));
    }
```

you can use

```
for (Subject subject : subjects) {
        classes.add(new Class(subject));
    }
```

Much more readable.

**Avoid manual loops where you can**

Instead of using this

```
    //fills profesorsName
    //Starts at 2 because 0 its name 1 its blocks
    for(int i = 2; i<lineSplitS.length; i++){
        profesorsName.add(lineSplitS[i]);
    }
```

use this

```
List<String> professors = Arrays.asList(lineSplitS).subList(2, lineSplitS.length)
profesorsName.addAll(professors);
```

The bottom line is manual loops give you a lot of errors. Off by one errors. Avoid them if you can.

**Use equals not == in Java to compare Strings. Always**

Didn't check but this may be a bug. Always use equals. You don't want to get surprised.

```
if(template[i][x] == posHours[y]){
                        avalide = true;
                    }
```

**Local variables are initalized. No need to do that again**

So this

```
int[] counter = new int[classes.size()];
    for (int s = 0; s < classes.size(); s++) {
        counter[s] = 0;
    }
```

does not need the loop.

- Smaller methods
- Less global variables